# Best way to run current for certain amount of time

Tags: current, time

I have a circuit set up that requires around 5 Amps of current to run but I need it to only run for a specific amount of time. The circuit is activated when I press a button and I want some tool to limit the amount of time current can pass through the circuit when the button is pressed. Does anyone have any ideas for a sort of timer I could use that is able to input and output 5+ A of current for a certain amount of time? Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Since someone asked, I want it to run for a short amount of time (maybe half a second) and it will have a voltage drop of around 15V

Comment: The question is pretty vague. What device it is and what voltage it runs at? Does it need 5+ amps for minutes, nanoseconds, or years, so what is the time range? How often the time will be triggered, once per year or at 10 kHz? How fast the current must be turned on or off and what kind of power supply provides it? These factors determine if this is something that needs to be custom designed or can simply be implemented by purchasing a mains socket timer.

Comment: https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2499334.m570.l1313&_nkw=relay+timer&_sacat=0